# Scope html element

Tags: typescript, singleton, angular

Recently I started to play with Angular 2 and TypeScript and I was wondering how I would be able to acces a `Singleton Class` throughout the webpage.

What i'm exacly making is a `UIManagerService` that currently holds only a `boolean` to check if a UI component is being accessed.

With this `boolean` I want a class to be toggeled on my `<html>` element :

```
.noselect {
    -o-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none; 
}
```

And acces it like this:

```
<html [class.noselect] = "UIManagerService.HoldingUI"> 
 ...
</html>
```

More `Components` will acces this `Singleton class` in the end.

---

**My Approach**

In other language I would use singleton classes for manager-like classes. This is the approach I also toke:

```
export class UIManagerService {
    holdingUI:Boolean;

    static instance : UIManagerService;
    static isCreating: Boolean = false;

    constructor() {
        if(!UIManagerService.isCreating) {
            throw new Error("You can't call new in singletong instance");
        }
    }

    static getInstance() {
        if(UIManagerService.instance == null) {
            UIManagerService.isCreating = true;
            UIManagerService.instance = new UIManagerService();
            UIManagerService.isCreating = false;
        }

        return UIManagerService.instance;
    }

    setHoldingUI(value) {
        this.holdingUI = value;
    }

    getHoldingUI() {
        return this.holdingUI;
    }
}
```

(props to [twofuckingdevelopers](http://twofuckingdevelopers.com/2015/04/angular-2-singleton-service/))

Now this works great once I try to acces it in a `Component`:

```
export class Slider { 

    constructor() {

    }

    mousedown(event) {
        UIManagerService.getInstance().setHoldingUI(true);
        console.log(UIManagerService.getInstance().getHoldingUI());
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Nkmol

Answer (score 2):

In angular2 you do not have to do anything special to create singleton service. By default they are singleton. So do use services concept provided by angular. Also it worth mentioning that you are not using dependency injection in your sample Slider component - this is bad due to numerous reasons. Both these issues are described in depth here: [dependency injection in angular2](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/18/dependency-injection-in-angular-2.html).

To access property or method exposed by service from your component you can create a simple wrapper property/method in the component:

```
@Component(.....)
export class Slider 
{ 
    private m_service: UIManagerService;

    constructor(service: UIManagerService)
    {
        this.m_service = service;
    }

    public test() 
    {
        this.m_service.test();
    }
}
```

and in bootstrap call:

bootstrap(
    Application, 
    [
        UIManagerService
    ]);

Comment: Thanks for you answer. However, this does not scope it to the whole document where even the `<html>` and `<body>` elements are included. It is why i have to use Singleton.

Comment: I don't see how `<body>` and "singleton" are related. Your questions contains a lot of code but it doesn't say (IMHO) what the actual problem is. You can't use binding like `[class.noselect]` outside the `<app-element>` tag, not even at the `<app-element [class.noselect]>` tag itself. From your question it looks like you're looking for something like https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/3c8fa8c50d820e3317bc40292c73df03c8b23e86/modules/angular2/src/platform/browser/title.ts

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer the relation for me was because I couldn't `bootstrap` something to my `<html>` element, I thought singelton was my only option. But as you stated, I will probably will not be able to scope it with `angular`. 
About the link you gave: I might aswell use plain javascript `document` to acces the `<html>` element? (see my answer)

Answer (score 2):

Agree with the already given answer.

One addition.

If you want Angular to still use your `getInstance` function to create your service (maybe you want to add more logic in there later other than just "newing" it up), you can do this.

In your `ui.manager.service.ts`:

```
import {provide} from 'angular2/core';

export class UIManagerService {
    holdingUI: boolean;

    static instance : UIManagerService;
    static isCreating: Boolean = false;

    constructor() {
        if(!UIManagerService.isCreating) {
            throw new Error("You can't call new in singleton instance");
        }
    }

    static getInstance(): UIManagerService {
        if(UIManagerService.instance == null) {
            UIManagerService.isCreating = true;
            UIManagerService.instance = new UIManagerService();
            UIManagerService.isCreating = false;
        }

        return UIManagerService.instance;
    }

    setHoldingUI(value): void {
        this.holdingUI = value;
    }

    getHoldingUI(): boolean {
        return this.holdingUI;
    }

    test(): void {
        console.log("This is coming from UIManagerService");
    }
}

export let UIManagerServiceProvider = provide(UIManagerService, {
    useFactory: () => {
        return UIManagerService.getInstance();
    }
});
```

Export the `UIManagerServiceProvider` which invokes the `getInstance`.

In your main application (for me it's app.component.ts):

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {UIManagerService, UIManagerServiceProvider} from './ui.manager.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<h1 (mousedown)="_uiManagerService.test()">Angular 2 App</h1>`,
    providers: [UIManagerServiceProvider]
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private _uiManagerService: UIManagerService) {
    }
}
```

As you can see in the template you can just call the `test` function.

```
(mousedown)="_uiManagerService.test()"
```

Comment: Really cool. Did not know about this! However, I still cannot acces the `<html>` element as, from what i've read, Angular 2 does not acces the outside the `<body>` element and never acces the `document`.

Answer (score 0):

Because Angular 2 does not seem to be able to scope the `<html>` element, I fixed this simply by using plain javascript:

**Slider.ts**

```
export class Slider { 

    constructor() {

    }

    mousedown() {
        UIManagerService.getInstance().setHoldingUI(true);
    }

    mouseup() {
        UIManagerService.getInstance().setHoldingUI(false);
    }
}
```

No need for injection as I can't bootstrap something as it is outside the scope.

**UIManagerService.ts**

```
export class UIManagerService {
    holdingUI:Boolean;
    htmlClass = 'noselect';

    static instance : UIManagerService;
    static isCreating: Boolean = false;

    constructor() {
        if(!UIManagerService.isCreating) {
            throw new Error("You can't call new in singletong instance");
        }
    }

    static getInstance() {
        if(UIManagerService.instance == null) {
            UIManagerService.isCreating = true;
            UIManagerService.instance = new UIManagerService();
            UIManagerService.isCreating = false;
        }

        return UIManagerService.instance;
    }

    setHoldingUI(value) {
        if(value)
            this.addHTMLClass();
        else 
            this.removeHTMLClass();
        this.holdingUI = value;
    }

    getHoldingUI() {
        return this.holdingUI;
    }

    // Toggle specific class
    toggleHtmlClass() {
       document.documetElement.classList.toggle(this.htmlClass);
    }
}
```

---

This isn't the most clean solution however it does the job. For now I keep this answer *until there is a better answer*.